# Date() method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript countdown timer that will allow the user to enter a particular time e.g(15mins - 00:15:00). Then, the script will determine the date and time I currently have. Then, it will add 15 minutes on top of the current time and date.

For example, set time is 15 mins and the current time is 20:00:00(8pm).

The script will know that 20:15:00 is my end time and it will calculate how much time is left such as a normal timer would do.

However, if the set time has exceeded 23:00:00 (11pm since 12am is 00:00:00 military time), the date does not increment and the time normally adds up to 25:00:00++ that is now an invalid input for date and time.

Please help. How do I make the time to continue counting from 00:00:00 if it exceeds 23:00:00 at the add another day to date?

I tried using ternary operators but it doesn't work properly.

Please see my source codes for reference:

```js
var hour = document.getElementById("hrs").value;
    var min = document.getElementById("mins").value;
    var sec = document.getElementById("sec").value;
    var newTime = new Date();
    var curr_year = newTime.getFullYear();
    var curr_Month = newTime.getMonth();
    var curr_date = newTime.getDate();
    var todayDate = (curr_year + " " + (curr_Month + 1) + " " + curr_date);
    

    newTime.setHours(newTime.getHours() + hour);
    newTime.setMinutes(newTime.getMinutes() + min);
    newTime.setSeconds(newTime.getSeconds() + sec);
    var newTime = (newTime.getHours() + parseInt(hour)) + ":" + (newTime.getMinutes() + parseInt(min)) + ":" + (newTime.getSeconds() + parseInt(sec));
    var timeDateNow = todayDate + " " + newTime;

function myTime1() {
    var hour = document.getElementById("hrs").value;
    var min = document.getElementById("mins").value;
    var sec = document.getElementById("sec").value;
    var newTime = new Date();
    var curr_year = newTime.getFullYear();
    var curr_Month = newTime.getMonth();
    var curr_date = newTime.getDate();
    var todayDate = (curr_year + " " + (curr_Month + 1) + " " + curr_date);
    
    var newTime = (((newTime.getHours() + parseInt(hour)) > 25 ? (newTime.getHours() + parseInt(hour)) - 25 : (newTime.getHours() + parseInt(hour)))
    + ":" + 
    ((newTime.getMinutes() + parseInt(min)) > 60 ? (newTime.getMinutes() + parseInt(min)) - 60 : (newTime.getMinutes() + parseInt(min))) 
    + ":" + 
    ((newTime.getSeconds() + parseInt(sec)) > 60 ? (newTime.getSeconds() + parseInt(sec)) - 60 : (newTime.getSeconds() + parseInt(sec))));

    alert(newTime);
    

    var timeDateNow = todayDate + " " + newTime;

    // alert(timeDateNow);
    $.post('updateTimerTime.php',
    {
        'timer1_update'     : true,
        'timeInitiate'      : timeDateNow
    }, function(data, status) 
    {
        // alert(data);
    });
    // alert(newTime);
    location.reload();
}
var gettingTimerTime = "<?php echo $time_1; ?>";
var countDownDate = new Date(gettingTimerTime).getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

    var now = new Date().getTime();

    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    var hours = (Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60))) < 10 ? "0"+(Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60))) : (Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)));
    var minutes = (Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60))) < 10 ? "0"+(Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60))) : (Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)));
    var seconds = (Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)) < 10 ? "0" + (Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)) : (Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000));
    document.getElementById("timetimer1").innerHTML = hours + ":"
    + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
    $.post('updateSwitch1.php', {
        'updateSwitchToOff1' : true
    }, function(data,status){
        // alert(status);
    });
        document.getElementById("timetimer1").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post">
<div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center" style="
  text-align: center;margin-bottom: 20px; z-index: 1;">
<input type="number" id="hrs" value="00" style="width: 40px; text-align: center;" maxlength="2">
<input type="number" id="mins" value="00" style="width: 40px; text-align: center;" maxlength="2">
<input type="number" id="sec" value="00" style="width: 40px; text-align: center;" maxlength="2">
<input type="button" id="btnTime1" onclick="myTime1()" value="Go">

  </div>
  <div>
  </div><br>
  <div class="row" style="z-index: 1;">
    <p id="timetimer1" style="font-size: 50px; text-align: center;"></p>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: JavaScript dates recalculate if you give them out-of-bounds values. For example, if you set `seconds` to `60` then it will automatically increase `minutes` by `1` and set `seconds` to `0`. Using this, you can just take the number of seconds, increase it by how long the counter should be, and JavaScript will automatically handle advancing through minutes, hours, days, months, years...

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Javascript countdown timer that will allow the user to enter a particular time e.g(15mins - 00:15:00). Then, the script will determine the date and time I currently have. Then, it will add 15 minutes on top of the current time and date.

```
var incr = 1000 * 60 * 15; // 15 min
var date = new Date();
var incrDate = new Date(date.getTime() + incr);
```

`Date.prototype.getTime` will give you the current datetime in milliseconds, so if you add 15 minutes worth of milliseconds and then pass that to the Date constructor you'll get a new Date object with the specified date and time.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to ensure the date is a valid one, [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object do that by themselves e.g. :

```js
a = new Date("2018-08-23T23:00:00")
console.log(a)

min = 75
sec = 0

a.setSeconds(a.getSeconds() + sec + min * 60)
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Although this *might* work in a given JavaScript implementation, the Date constructor is only required to parse datestrings in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which yours is not. Also the Date constructor does *not* guarantee a valid date, you have to check the `.getTime` method or some other check `invalid = new Date('foo'); invalid.getTime(); // NaN`.

Comment: @JaredSmith the string I used in constructor is the one returned by `Date.toString()` except I removed the timezone part, Thought it was the correct format . Op use `new Date()` so he got no problem with this, I used this one in my exemple because it is next to midnight which is the problem in this question

Comment: [Link](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) to the relevant section of the language specification. Your code is not guaranteed to work portably.

Comment: @JaredSmith edited at the same time you sent the comment ;)

Comment: Is there a way for me to have an output of "YYYY MM DD Hr:min:sec" instead of the whole 'Thu Aug 23 2018 23:15:00 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)'?

Comment: @DeanBayaca you can call [`Date.toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/toJSON) for `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss`

Comment: @jonatjano, it gives me this particular format "2018-08-23T15:15:00.000Z". Thanks for the suggestion though!